# Multiprocessing inside module creating loop instead of running target method

Tags: python, aws-lambda, multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a set of lambda calls which work in parallel to do some processing of data.  These methods return their bits of data back to the parent process, which then combines it all.

I need to be able to run this locally as well for a testing script which runs several test cases and scores the accuracy of the processing.  To do this, I mock the lambda calls and import the lambda as a module and execute the handler directly.

So my top level lambda, uses multiprocessing.Process to call methods which invoke the other lambdas like so:

```
# Top Level Lambda

l = client('lambda')

def process_data(data, conn):
  response = l.Invoke(
    FunctionName = os.environ.get('PROCESS_FUNCTION'),
    InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
    LogType = 'Tail',
    Payload = json.dump({
      'data': data
    })
  )
    
  conn.send(response.Payload.read())
  conn.close()
    
def create(datas)
  p_parent, p_child = mp.Pipe()
  process = mp.Process(target=process_data, args=(datas[0], p_child))
  process.start()
```

I've cut out a lot of code to give the gist here.  I get an error on process.start()

> ```
>    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
>    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
>
>    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
>    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
>    in the main module:
>
>        if __name__ == '__main__':
>            freeze_support()
>            ...
>
>    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
>    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
> ```

I've tried putting in freeze_support calls in each lambda in a `__name__ == '__main__'` block, I've tried putting it in the lambda handler, and I have tried putting it in the test script, but I always get the same error.

What really throws me here is that the new process doesn't call the target function at all, but instead runs the test script from the beginning and the 2nd call to invoke a new process in that subprocess is what is giving me the error

Comment: The key thing to remember is that the new process starts from scratch, and has to reimport your main module from the beginning.  That means it runs EVERYTHING in your main file.  The error says that your main file is starting another process.  What you want is for the "subprocess" stuff to be in code that is only run when `__name__ == "__main__"`,  The "freeze" stuff is a red herring.

Comment: For example, if you have `create(data)` at column 0, that would cause this problem.  You want `def main():` / `  create(data)`  /  `if __name__ == "__main__":` / `    main()`

Comment: ah, gotcha, so since my script wasn't running in a ```__name__ == '__main__'``` block, it was running it again.  I just remedied that and it is working..  thanks